# Combined GAN function expects input axis of -1. Works in Jupyter not in Colab

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have been working with a ciphar-10 GAN and it works well in Jupyter notebooks, but in Colab I am getting the error:

> Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected
>   axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape
>   [None, 32, 32, 3]

I assume I need to reshape this, but I am not sure why it works in Jupyter. Any suggestions will be helpful.

The code for the generator model is as follows:

```
def define_generator(latent_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    # foundation for 4x4 image
    n_nodes = 256 * 4 * 4
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=latent_dim))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Reshape((4, 4, 256)))
    # upsample to 8x8
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    # upsample to 16x16
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    # upsample to 32x32
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    # output layer
    model.add(Conv2D(3, (3,3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
    return model
```

Thank you. (model: "sequential_10 is the same as Sequential 9")

[model summary and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODN93.png)

Answer (score 0):

See if you are loading an RGB image (3 channels) instead of grey scale (1 channel).

Comment: I am using the ciphar10 dataset included with Keras. I just checked the X_train array and it is of shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)

Comment: Since this is the generator part, you have to use the encoded data as input to the generator, not the original image